# firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to add the Firebase script in my html, after initializing Firebase app with `firebase.initializeApp(config);`.

So then I have this :

```
 <script>

          window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', 
           {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': function(response) {
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            onSignInSubmit();
            }
      });

 </script>
```

Which provides the error :

```
firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor error
```

1. How to solve this error (found similar questions without a direct answer)
2. How to proceed from here with the full flow ?

**EDIT**:

I have this in the beginning of the html :

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

I am initializing the app with :

```
 <script>
          var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZQ14",
            authDomain: "xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "xxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});
     </script>
```

and those are the only things relate to Firebase I have in this file.

Comment: It looks like you're not import the Firebase Auth SDK into your page. Make sure you followed the steps in https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup, and update your question with the imports if you're still stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank, in your link I did not see anything about import, but I edited my question showing everything I have relate to Firebase. Please take a look

Comment: @Curnelious could you please write up your solution as an answer below?

Comment: Cool. Can you add an answer with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing version of the imported files with : (**thanks a lot Frank**)

```
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh right, didn't even notice the versions were different 