# firebase.fb.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying Firebase authentication in vuejs with vue-tel-input but I can't able to understand this error. Any help me to do this.

Here is the complete code https://codesandbox.io/s/phone-auth-vue-36vdv?file=/src/main.js

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272773/firebase-auth-recaptchaverifier-is-not-a-constructor-error

Comment: I think there is no problem with import  @mateonunez